# Facebook PHP sdk

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I work with facebook php sdk 5  , I create an application facebook . I put domain APP: localhost , AND  site URL :http://localhost/facebook-phpExpl/facebook-php-sdk/index.php .  I put it as public .I test it it work but now when I connect with other  accout it return

Application not configured: This application is currently under development, and you can not access it. Use an authorized user account or contact an application administrator to obtain an access right.

how can I configure application to connect with  public users . what can I put in  https URL (URL of the Privacy Policy)??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the App settings and find the toggle button to set it public under "App Review".

The Privacy Policy is only needed then you go online, it will not work with localhost anyway because Facebook needs to be able to access it.

Comment: thanks for your reply . I said that I set it public and it work with localhost only with my own account facebook but doesn't work with others account .

Comment: well...localhost only exists on your computer, you have to put it online, on a real server ;)

Comment: I try  just to test if work or no Then I will put it online I login to facebook and  get information .  so to connect with other account it will be online???                                                             https://www.dropbox.com/s/npdsu5y8oqh53se/login.png?dl=0 https://www.dropbox.com/s/yzgli2r17bhnj3s/login_facebook.png?dl=0 https://www.dropbox.com/s/hygtkari3mnos4y/details.png?dl=0

Comment: it has to be public, yes. make sure you know what localhost is, it´s important.